# How do I open console/Command prompt using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want to make a gui app with tkinter.
Later the application will open a command prompt and write some commands

I don't know how to load the command prompt into the GUI.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to execute some commands?  Or do you actually want to have a shell where the user can type in their own commands?

Comment: Yes, I want to run / execute some commands in cmd, This command will open/run node.js as server with npm.  Soo  i need to display the command(.cmd) into my GUI.

Comment: Well, what you'll do is use `subcommand.Popen` to start the command, then read output from the stdout pipe and display it in a window in your app.  There are good examples on that on the interwebs.

Comment: @TimRoberts did you mean `subprocess.Popen`? anyways, here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)